# Autofiltering is not working with vba and criteria as text

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with products. Sometimes some products may be unavailable.

So I created a function =iferror( cell value, "ERROR") to display the word ERROR.

Now in my VBA I have the following to create an autofilter to display all products apart from products containing ERROR

```
Set tbl = Worksheets("FOR EXPORT").ListObjects("MyTable")
'SET AUTOFILTER
tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>*ERROR*"
```

I have this

```
Set tbl = Worksheets("FOR EXPORT").ListObjects("Mytable")
'SET AUTOFILTER
tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>*ERROR*"

'SET PATH
csvFilePath = "C:\Users\Maindesk\Desktop\CSVFile_" & Format(Date, "ddmmmyyyy") & "_" & Format(Time, "hAM/PM") & ".csv"


Dim VisRng As Range
' set the new Range object to the visible cells of `tbl.Range`
Set VisRng = tbl.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
' copy only the visible cells in range to array
tblArr = VisRng.Value


'SET FILE OUTPUT
fNum = FreeFile()
Open csvFilePath For Output As #fNum

For i = 1 To UBound(tblArr)

    rowArr = Application.Index(tblArr, i, 0)
    csvVal = VBA.Join(rowArr, ";")
    Print #1, csvVal

Next
```

BUT I get not all products nevertheless the criteria instead of getting 368 - 7 products I get 196 products. There are 5 cells with ERROR and 2 cells with Empty values

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code so the problem is within the data or the naming conventions. Are you sure it is the third field? Do you have hidden coluns?

Comment: Have you inspected tblArr in the locals window?

Comment: I think I get type mismatch I did debug.print tblarr

Comment: In locals tblArr has 196 rows